# Redshift jdbc connection configuration with Spring boot 2 not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-redshift, spring-jdbc, spring-web

Here are my dependencies in build.gradle.

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
compile group: 'com.amazon.redshift', name: 'redshift-jdbc42', version: '1.2.10.1009'
compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-util', version: '9.4.11.v20180605'
compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.0.0.CR1'
compile group: 'com.vladmihalcea', name: 'hibernate-types-52', version: '2.2.2'
```

When I start my application,It's not able to start tomcat server. I am getting following error,

```
2018-06-29 18:43:47.296 ERROR 16568 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@70fe2b64]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4907) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5042) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined
    at java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1112) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.<init>(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.getInstanceInternal(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.java:77) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.registerURLStreamHandlerFactory(StandardRoot.java:699) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.initInternal(StandardRoot.java:682) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2018-06-29 18:43:47.299 ERROR 16568 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ci.vrbc.costanalysis.recommendation.CostAnalysisApplication.main(CostAnalysisApplication.java:34) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2018-06-29 18:43:47.301  INFO 16568 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-06-29 18:43:47.304  WARN 16568 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2018-06-29 18:43:47.305  INFO 16568 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-06-29 18:43:47.338  INFO 16568 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-06-29 18:43:47.348 ERROR 16568 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ci.vrbc.costanalysis.recommendation.CostAnalysisApplication.main(CostAnalysisApplication.java:34) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:949) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    ... 24 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried all types of solutions available online regarding tomcat not running, like changing the redshift dependencies to noawssdk module, changing the ctomcat verion etc. but none worked for me. Can someone please help me here ?

Comment: I don't think your issue has anything to do with `Redshift`, try changing it to some other database for debugging.

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.  The Redshift driver on the classpath for my spring boot app causes the app not to start due to an embedded tomcat error.  If I get rid of the driver, everything works fine.  The other thing I've noticed is the problem only occurs when I run the app from my IDE (IntelliJ). Building the Spring Boot jar with Maven and launching from the command line seems to work even with the Redshift driver on the classpath.

Comment: I think I was wrong about the IDE being an issue.  While I'm not able to reproduce this problem from the command line, I think that's just due to "luck" with the classloader.

Comment: Has anybody found a solution for this one?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Redshift calls `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()` from its JarInJarClassLoader class, while embedded Tomcat also calls that same method from `org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.` Here's what `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()` looks like:

```
  /**
 * Sets an application's {@code URLStreamHandlerFactory}.
 * This method can be called at most once in a given Java Virtual
 * Machine.
 *
 *<p> The {@code URLStreamHandlerFactory} instance is used to
 *construct a stream protocol handler from a protocol name.
 *
 * <p> If there is a security manager, this method first calls
 * the security manager's {@code checkSetFactory} method
 * to ensure the operation is allowed.
 * This could result in a SecurityException.
 *
 * @param      fac   the desired factory.
 * @exception  Error  if the application has already set a factory.
 * @exception  SecurityException  if a security manager exists and its
 *             {@code checkSetFactory} method doesn't allow
 *             the operation.
 * @see        java.net.URL#URL(java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
 *             int, java.lang.String)
 * @see        java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory
 * @see        SecurityManager#checkSetFactory
 */
public static void setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URLStreamHandlerFactory fac) {
    synchronized (streamHandlerLock) {
        if (factory != null) {
            throw new Error("factory already defined");
        }
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null) {
            security.checkSetFactory();
        }
        handlers.clear();
        factory = fac;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can only call it once per JVM.  So it seems the solution would be to stop either Redshift or embedded Tomcat from calling the method.  It looks like `TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.disable()` will stop embedded Tomcat from doing so, but I'm not sure what additional consequences that will incur.  I did find [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10529) discussion on the topic, which seems to imply there are side effects.  Another option might be to make the Redshift driver load after Tomcat starts, assuming that the Redshift code handles that condition properly.  From what I can tell after a quick search the driver isn't open source so I can't verify whether that will work.  Another option would be to switch from Tomcat to another embedded servlet container--I tried switching to Jetty and that seemed to work for me.